# Displaying Field type with Java reflection

Tags: java, class, reflection, types, field

I am using reflection in Java.

Here is my code:

```
  public String getClassFields(Class aClass)
  {
  String ClassFields = "";
  Field[] Fields = aClass.getDeclaredFields();
  boolean isPublic;
  String separator = System.getProperty( "line.separator" );
  for (Field f : Fields) 
  {
    isPublic = Modifier.isPublic(f.getModifiers());
    if (isPublic)
        ClassFields += "public " + f.getType() + " " + f.getName() + separator;
    else
        ClassFields += "private " + f.getType() + " " + f.getName() + separator;
  }    
  return ClassFields;
```

}

If the fields in the Class are as follows:

```
private int Diameter;
private Colour Colour;
```

The code I have posted above returns the following:

```
private int Diameter
private class Colour Colour
```

How can I modify my code to remove the additional 'class' word from the line:

```
private class Colour Colour
```

Comment: call `replace` with `"class "`, `""` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Right now, you're getting the default string representation, provided by [`Class#toString()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#toString%28%29):

> Converts the object to a string. The string representation is the string "class" or "interface", followed by a space, and then by the fully qualified name of the class in the format returned by `getName`. If this `Class` object represents a primitive type, this method returns the name of the primitive type. If this `Class` object represents void this method returns "void".

So you want to use a different method to get the name of the class. Change

```
f.getType()
```

to

```
((Class) f.getType()).getName()
// or
((Class) f.getType()).getSimpleName()
```

---

Side note: don't perform string concatenation in a loop like that. Because it has to copy the string each time, that leads to quadratic (`O(n^2)`) asymptotic runtime. Use a [`StringBuilder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) instead.